# Import Comments from Facebook Comment Plugin & export to disqus

Tags: facebook-comments, disqus

I'm migrating my site's existing comment system from fb to Disqus. Now problem is that it I will lost all the comments, Is there a way I can "migrate them"?

How to import facebook comment ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to import Facebook comments out of the box to Disqus, but it is possible with some development work. The best method is to export comments from the Facebook graph and then format it to a custom Disqus WXR file documented here: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472150